# "Parse error at line 1 column 1" when using QConsolidate3 to share QGIS projects

Tags: qgis

I am trying to save a project and layers as a zip file to share with colleagues but I am receiving an error message when I do so:

> Parse error at line 1 column 1

I am using QGIS desktop 3.2.3 and QConsolidate3.

Comment: welcome to GIS SE! It's probably a good idea to mention which version of QGIS, your OS (Windows/Mac/Linux) and the version of the plugin (you can find this in the plugin manager window).

Comment: thanks for that! Just tried it and I see exactly the same thing (I'm on QGIS 3.2.0), and using the latest version of the plugin

Comment: I don't know this particular error, but I would be suspicious of an odd layer name or an odd column name. You could start by removing half your layers (in a copy!) and see if the problem persists, repeating as necessary. If you can narrow it down to one layer, repeat the general process by removing columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> tl;dr - save your project as .qgs, not .qgz

I've had a look at the code and seen a few things that might need looked at

In particular I see lots of references to '.qgs' as the project filename extension. In 3.2.0 at least, the project file extension seems to be .qgz by default (at least for projects I've created in 3.2). I must have missed the memo on that :)

Because it assumes the file is .qgs, it can't find the file, so the file is empty. An empty document is not valid XML, which is why it fails on line 1 column 1.

If you can find a way of changing this default to use the old .qgs format, that might be worth a try? (Don't try to rename the file extension manually; I think qgz is a [compressed format](https://oslandia.com/en/2018/06/01/qgz-a-new-default-project-file-format-for-qgis/)).

Have tried hacking my local copy of the plugin but to no avail :-(

**EDIT** have [raised issue](https://github.com/alexbruy/qconsolidate/issues/11) for you. This might not be the cause but it's worth a try!

**EDIT2** QConsolidate3 is actually a separate project. It's logged as an [issue already there](https://github.com/danzig666/qconsolidate3/issues/4)

Comment: I tried saving the file as a .qgs and the consolidation worked!

Upon sending it, there were a number of "bad layers" when it doesn't seem that anything is wrong with them, but that seems to be a different issue.

Comment: that sounds like you have some memory layers, those will vanish if you try to share them, indeed that's a different issue :)